# VI SDK Cluster Memory

Tags: java, sdk, virtual-machine

I need help in getting the Cluster Reserved Memory and the Used Memory using the Vi Java SDK Program,

I am able to get the total memory of cluster using the below code.

```
ClusterComputeResource crs=(ClusterComputeResource) mes[i];
ClusterConfigInfo clusconfig=crs.getConfiguration();
ComputeResourceSummary cm=crs.getSummary();
double mem=cm.getTotalMemory()/1099511627776D;
double round=Math.round(mem);
String str = String.format("%1.2f", mem);
double totalmemory = Double.valueOf(str);
System.out.println("Cluster NAME " + crs.getName());
System.out.println("Cluster Memory " + totalmemory +"TB");
```

Can any one guide me further to get the reserved and used memory of clusters.

please help and Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read the documentation, The data object [ClusterComputeResource](https://www.vmware.com/support/developer/vc-sdk/visdk2xpubs/ReferenceGuide/vim.ComputeResource.Summary.html) has one more property called

`effectiveMemory : Effective memory resources (in MB) available to run virtual machines. This is the aggregated effective resource level from all running hosts. Hosts that are in maintenance mode or are unresponsive are not counted. Resources used by the VMware Service Console are not included in the aggregate. This value represents the amount of resources available for the root resource pool for running virtual machines.` .

Now to calculate used memory you have to do some calculation. It is not that straight forward(TotalMemory - EffectiveMem).

EDIT: I assume you want the storage capacity ?
To retrieve the capacity of cluster , Check that the Cluster object has a array of datastore object. Iterate through the array and retrieve the datastore capacity.

```
ManagedEntity[] clusters = new InventoryNavigator(rootFolder).searchManagedEntities("ClusterComputeResource");      
ClusterComputeResource cluster = (ClusterComputeResource)clusters[0];
Datastore[] datastores = cluster.getDatastores();
for(Datastore datastore: datastores)
    System.out.println("Capacity for datastore " +datastore.getName() + ": " + datastore.getSummary().capacity +" bytes");
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply,it helped for my requirement.i have one more thing to get the "reserved Capacity of clusters" ,how can i get that?

Comment: Thank you for the reply.Actually i am trying to get the memory reserved capacity which will be displayed in the "Resource allocation" in Vsphere client .

Comment: Hi Reuben,I got the Memory Reserved Capacity by using the "ResourcePoolRuntimeInfo" .Thank you so much for your help..